# How to add extra latency/delay for MacBook audio output?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

Is it possible to programmatically add extra latency to the audio output? E.g., 500ms or 1000ms to headphones 3.5mm out?

Can this be done via OS settings or CLI built-in tools?

Are there some free or open-source projects for that stuff?

Comment: Perhaps if you give a reason, or reasons, for the need to add latency, you will get more targeted responses.

Comment: I didn't want to flood the post with unnecessary information. But I can write this info here:

I use the SoundSwitch app for controlling light fixtures via DMX.
Also, I use the EasyView2 app for 3D visualization.

I can not connect these two apps via the internal network (using art-net), so I connect them like this: 
USB-Out -> SoundSwith interface -> DMX cable - Sushi-DS interface -> USB-In. 
DMX signals go from the laptop via one interface and return via another.

Comment: When I built light scenes for some songs in SoundSwith and saw its visualization in the EasyView2 app, I got a latency between audio from the SoundSwitch app and visualization in EasyView2 during a long roundtrip of DMX signal. So, I want to add a delay to the audio output to see my visualization synced with the audio.